# ORMLite or SQLite in android

Tags: android

Why we use *ORMLite*, if we already have *Sqlite* in Android ?
Is there any specific reason behind the ORMLite to use over SQLite in Android?

Comment: With ORMLite is easier convert the database registers to an class instance, so is an object relational database mapper.

Comment: Thanks,but someone asked to me, to give the valid reason that why we use ORMLite instead of SQLite. If internally ORMLite use SQLite.